# Как отличить сложное предложение с односоставными частями от простого с однородными сказуемыми?

Tags: синтаксис, запятые, сложное-предложение

Итак, есть предложение:
"Живите счастливо, радуйтесь каждому дню". Это предложение простое с однородными сказуемыми.
Добавим союз "но", он, собственно, ничего не поменяет: "Живите счастливо, но радуйтесь каждому дню". Все те же однородные сказуемые, только теперь разделены союзом "но".
А теперь такое предложение:
"Семь раз отмерь - один раз отрежь". Это уже бессоюзное сложное предложение, тире можем заменить союзом "но". Получаем: "Семь раз отмерь, но один раз отрежь". Таким образом, предложения "Живите счастливо, но радуйтесь каждому дню" и "Семь раз отмерь, но один раз отрежь" невероятно схожи, но одно сложное, а другое простое. Так как отличать простое от сложного в подобных случаях?

Comment: Обращу Ваше внимание, что в предложении "Семь раз отмерь —  один раз отрежь" для каждой части можно задать общий вопрос: "Что именно мы режем и отмеряем?", а вот в предложении "Живите счастливо, радуйтесь каждому дню" этого нет.  Я к тому, что второе предложение, на мой взгляд, даже больше похоже на предложение с однородными сказуемостными, чем первое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цитата: *А теперь такое предложение: "Семь раз отмерь — один раз отрежь". Это уже **бессоюзное сложное предложение**.*

**А почему это БСП?** Почему не однородные члены? Между однородными членами при бессоюзной связи тоже может ставиться **тире**:

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=97#pp97

4. **При противопоставлении** между однородными членами предложения, не связанными союзами, ставится тире: Не за горами смерть-то — за плечами (Т.); Не небесам чужой отчизны — я песни родине слагал (Н.); Ему хотелось не говорить — кричать об этом;  Он не то что сочиняет — фантазирует.

Здесь глагол в форме **повелительного наклонения**, поэтому по грамматике это односоставное **определенно-личное** предложение с двумя однородными сказуемыми.

По семантике же его следует отнести к **обобщенно-личному** предложению с двумя однородными сказуемыми, так как это обращение не к конкретному лицу, а к обобщенному (любому).

Comment: Sharon, рискую снова навлечь Ваш гнев, но скажите, ГДЕ сказано, что повелительное наклонение говорит об однородности членов простого предложения? Вопрос об однородности сказуемых вообще сложен: https://studopedia.net/8_66712_vopros-ob-odnorodnih-skazuemih.html  Данное же предложение во многих упражнениях и в заданиях ЕГЭ приводится как БСЛ, вот одно: https://reshak.ru/otvet/reshebniki.php?otvet=187&predmet=ladizhenskaya9

Comment: https://scicenter.online/sintaksis-scicenter/odnorodnyie-glavnyie-chlenyi-126266.html :
"И опять-таки не случайно, что единомыслие в решении вопроса обнаруживается при обращении к односоставным предложениям: перечисляющийся ряд сказуемых, выраженных глаголами, безоговорочно зачисляется в разряд сложных предложений: Подсудимых тоже куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад (Л. Т.)".

Comment: Мир вообще очень сложен. Изучая его, мы пользуемся определенными моделями, отвлекаясь от несущественных признаков и рассматривая главные. Для школьного уровня - одна модель, для филологов-специалистов, изучающих данную тему, модель будет другая. Хуже всего, когда люди, не имея опыта работы с простыми вещами, стремятся к познанию сложного.  Я в своем ответе привожу школьную модель, надо сначала с ней разобраться. Почему она не подходит, почему надо выходить на другой уровень?  А один из самых сложных вопросов в лингвистике пусть лингвисты и решают.

Comment: Так что предлагаю считать  ваш ответ, который всем нравится, единственно правильным, а я устала отвечать. Иногда  я чувствую себя как эти подсудимые, которых" куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад..."

Comment: Так ведь и я о школьной модели - в школе это бессоюзные сложные предложения (Семь раз отмерь - один раз отрежь), по крайней мере 33 года, которые я там проработала, так считалось, не думаю, что теперь по-другому. А насчёт "который всем нравится", поддержали всего 2 человека, это далеко не все, другие самоустранились. Или сомневаются, потому что это действительно неоднозначно решаемый вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Это один из самых сложных вопросов в лингвистике.

Валгина объясняет, что однородные сказуемые вообще сомнительное понятие, многие учёные так и не признают их до сих пор, а уж про однородные сказуемые в односоставных предложениях и говорить нечего. Здесь нужно разбираться с количеством грамматических основ, а каждое сказуемое и есть основа, следовательно, формально  - сколько сказуемых, столько и предложений. Если исходить из понятия однородности, то однородные члены занимают одну синтаксическую позицию и относятся к одному члену предложения, значит, и в односоставном  тоже должен быть общий член.

> Главные члены  безличных предложений однородны, если объединены общей
>   связкой: Было тихо, сумрачно и скучно (М. Г.). Такие предложения часто
>   имеют обстоятельственный или объектный распространитель: В саду было
>   тихо, прохладно (Ч.); Его знобило и лихорадило (Сераф.); В начале
>   улицы еще было ветрено, и дорога была заметена, но в середине деревни
>   стало тихо, тепло и весело (Л. Т.); Во рту было сухо и противно от
>   металлического вкуса (Ч.). В предложениях без связки лучше усматривать
>   части сложного: Пустынно и темно (Семушк.).
>
> Предложения
>   определенно-личные и  обобщенно-личные с несколькими главными членами
>   могут быть как простыми с однородными сказуемыми, так и сложными, в
>   целом представляя тип переходный: Объеду еще раз и, как вернусь, пойду
>   к генералу и попрошу его (Л. Т.); Глядишь и не знаешь, идет или не
>   идет его величавая ширина (Г.); За перегородкой пошептались и замолкли
>   (Л. Т.); Ему верили, его хорошо знали (А.Н. Т.).

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm

В общем, это случай переходный, каждый считает, что он прав, в разных учебниках встретите разные версии. В школе идут формальным путём и в односоставных определённо-личных предложениях не усматривают однородных сказуемых, в односоставных безличных однородными будут сказуемые с общим членом - детерминантом: В парке пусто и ветрено. Студентов приучают  вдумываться: 1) когда подставляете местоимение ты, вы, мы - представляете одного собеседника или разных, это ведь в основном обобщённо-личные предложения; 2) одна это ситуация или разные; нельзя ли повторить местоимение.

Объеду еще раз и, как вернусь, (я) пойду к генералу и попрошу его (Л. Т.)- сложное, разные ситуации: сначала объеду, потом пойду и попрошу. А вот пойду и попрошу - однородные.

*Живите счастливо, но радуйтесь каждому дню.* - явно обращаются к одним и тем же собеседникам, простое.

*Семь раз отмерь - один раз отрежь*. *Семь раз отмерь, но один раз отрежь.* -обобщённо-личное предложение, и собеседник кто угодно, и ситуации по времени разные и даже противопоставленные: сначала отмерь, а потом отрежь. Вот (Ты) отмерь и отрежь - всё сейчас сделай, это однородные сказуемые.

А вообще, такие ситуации, когда нужно точно определить вид таких предложений, очень редки, если только в узкой научной среде, ведь знаки препинания одинаковы, а как назвать - разницы нет.