# Запятая между одинаковыми глаголами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сказуемые, и, авторская-пунктуация

Цитирую отрывок из "Иерусалима" А. Мура в переводе С. Карпова. Стр. 835.

> Я вижу Томаса а Беккета, и вижу смуглую женщину со шрамом, которая
> работает в корпусе Святого Петра в две тысячи двадцать пятом году.

"Вижу" и "вижу" — это два однородных сказуемых, соединённых союзом "и". В таких случаях запятая не требуется.

Есть причины для постановки запятой?

**Дополнение**

Привожу цитату из оригинального романа. Запятая там тоже есть.

> I see Audrey Vernall on the dance-hall stage, her fingers trickling on
> the keys of her accordion, tossing back her hair, with one small blue
> shoe keeping time on the worn boards, skirt swinging, “When The Saints
> Go Marching In” . Her tight smile falters in the spotlight and her
> eyes keeping darting sideways to the wings where her dad Johnny, the
> band’s manager, gives her the thumbs-up, nods encouragingly at her,
> and then, later on, he’s taking off his loud checked jacket, hanging
> it up on the hook for dressing gowns behind her bedroom door. **I see
> Thomas Becket, and I see the brown-skinned woman with the scar who
> works from the St. Peter’s Annexe up in two thousand and twenty-five.**
> I see the saints go marching in.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что здесь имеет место *присоединительный союз **и***, а не соединительный.
Вот что об этом говорит Розенталь ([Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120)):

**1.** Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат *дополнительные разъяснения* или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) **запятыми** (реже используются **тире, точка, многоточие**). Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами *даже, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, **и** (‘и притом’), да, да и, да и вообще, да и только* и др.
*А Рудин заговорил о самолюбии, **и очень дельно заговорил*** (Т.).
*Люди часто посмеиваются над ним, **и справедливо*** [посмеиваются] (Пан.).
[Сравните: Люди часто и справедливо посмеиваются над ним.]

**5.** Следует различать присоединительные союзы и соединительные союзы ***и, да,*** связывающие однородные члены предложения: перед присоединительным союзом ставится запятая, а перед неповторяющимся соединительным союзом никакого знака не требуется. Ср.:

*Автор статью представил, **и своевременно*** (*и* — союз присоединительный).
*Автор статью представил **в переработанном виде и своевременно*** (*и* — союз соединительный).

*Работу можно было давно уже сделать, **и даже лучше.**

Работу можно было сделать **скорее и даже лучше.***

Стоит отметить, что перед присоединительным союзом всегда присутствует отчетливая пауза (можно даже точку в этом месте поставить).
Я вижу Томаса а Беккета, и вижу смуглую женщину со шрамом...
Я вижу Томаса а Беккета. И вижу смуглую женщину со шрамом...

Comment: Спасибо за обстоятельный ответ. Сначала я его принял. Но рассуждения Sharon меня убедили в том, что этот случай не похож на примеры использования присоединительных союзов. Эти части выглядят действительно как равнозначные. Это не "даже", "скорее", "именно", а синтаксический эквивалент первой части. Поэтому извините, но я считаю справедливым снять в этом случае галочку. А плюс я Вам всё равно поставил, потому что версия отличная и подход добросовестный.

Answer (score 3):

**КОММЕНТАРИЙ**

Спасибо, Третий глаз, за вопрос, захвативший мое внимание. После дополнения с английским текстом он стал еще интереснее и понятнее. Сам я, прочитав такое предложение в переводе, не усомнился бы в правильности его пунктуации. Пусть глубины всех его грамматико-семантико-интонационных данных мне недоступны, но запятая не кажется лишней ни глазу, ни слуху.

Первым был ответ Риммы, и, как часто бывает, мне показалось, что он будет единственным. Я проголосовал, и даже не потому, что полностью соглашался с ним. Мой принцип здесь – ставить плюсы всему, что попало в поле моих интересов, грамотно написано, принесло в копилку хоть что-нибудь новое и было полезно.

На следующий день я прочитал ответ Sharon и комментарии к нему. Естественно, я ставлю плюс, хотя переход по ссылке ведет к целой книге и нужно время, чтобы найти там подтверждение "пересказа" и "гиперболизации" или всё же цитаты или очень близкого к ней текста. Не доверять Sharon у меня нет причин, думаю, что после слов "**Из вузовской грамматики**" идут два абзаца второго.

Если это так, то вывод "...мы можем считать данную конструкцию **сложным, а не простым предложением**..." мне кажется верным, даже если мы и не хотим принимать представленную версию за аксиому, где нет стопроцентных критериев разделения. Ну уж если приходится выбирать, то явно в сторону сложного предложения – мы же не можем поставить "промежуточную" запятую. И сейчас мне ближе этот подход. Запятая поддерживается со всех сторон – синтаксически (опущено второе подлежащее, присутствующее в оригинале), смыслово и интонационно.

Третий ответ, от Третьего глаза, меня тоже порадовал, несмотря на то что фраза  "**...мне не известны примеры...**" не говорит о невозможности иного. Особенно понравился последний абзац о нефункциональности союза ***и***, о его поэтичности. По этой версии ***и*** приближается к частице. Но всё же я склоняюсь к тому, что функция у него есть, и она больше соединительная (сочинительная), поскольку сказуемые играют равноправные роли, да и вообще выражены одной формой одного слова.

И пусть все три версии разные – каждая говорит однозначно: запятой быть, и каждая вносит свой вклад в формирование мнения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123258/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Answer (score 3):

Второй ответ от 20.04.2021 (обсуждение продолжено по просьбе автора вопроса)

Да, вопрос непростой. Я уже привела в комментарии ссылку на обсуждение подобной темы на форуме.  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458555/Как-отличить-сложное-предложение-с-односоставными-частями-от-простого-с-однородн](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458555/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD)

Один из ответов был, вероятно,  ориентирован на  вузовский учебник Валгиной  2003 года «Современный русский язык» http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/yanko.valgina_2003_416p_rasp_sl.htm#_Toc331393984

1. **О  грамматике однородных сказуемых**

Вот некоторые цитаты:

Таким образом, предложения с несколькими глагольными сказуемыми являют собой **переходный, промежуточный** тип между простым и сложным предложением.
При квалификации этого сложного синтаксического явления необходимо учесть его двойственную природу: с одной стороны, объединенность таких сказуемых общим подлежащим, с другой — расчлененность их предикативной основы.

Такие предложения являются переходными между простыми и сложными и, естественно, в частных, конкретных своих проявлениях **тяготеют то к одному, то к другому** из этих полярных типов.

Кроме того, возможность **вставки подлежащего** «он»  характеризует подобные сочетания сказуемых как отдельные предикативные единицы, что возможно в структуре сложного предложения. Например: ...Он не думал, чтобы картина его была лучше всех Рафаэлевых, но он знал, что того, что он хотел передать и передал в этой картине, никто никогда не передавал (Л. Т.). Ср.: Он не думал... но знал.

Таким образом, «однородные глагольные сказуемые» — понятие по меньшей мере сомнительное.

**2.  О пунктуации  в предложении с однородными сказуемым**

Итак, однородные сказуемые должны занимать **одно синтаксическое место** и входить в  единую предикативную основу. Изображенные действия  являются однородными, если объединены общей темой. Компактность расположения,  одинаковая грамматическая форма, отсутствие собственных распространителей – это классика для однородных сказуемых.

Если все это не проявляется в должной мере, то на каком-то этапе появляется **переходность,** а потом мы начинаем вообще  считать сказуемые отдельными предикативными единицами, то есть предложение определяется **как сложное.** Но это все грамматика, **а как быть с пунктуацией.** Если двигаться дальше в сторону осложнения, то это должно отражаться и на знаках препинания тоже.

**Так отражается или нет?** Лингвисты аккуратно обходят этот вопрос. Вот предложение: ***Подсудимых тоже куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад.*** Это предложение безоговорочно зачисляется в разряд сложных, **но запятой нет**. В других случаях предложение названо сложным, но в нем используется **союз НО,** который нам ни о чем не говорит. *Он приобрел свой прежний человеческий облик, // но был чрезвычайно мрачен и даже, пожалуй, раздражен.*

Я же думаю, что качественный **переход** от однородных сказуемых к сложному предложению происходит именно в тот момент, когда появляется **потребность в постановке запятой**,  для этого даже не надо знать грамматических тонкостей в классификации сложных и осложненных предложений.

Автор осознает необходимость в разграничении **двух ситуаций** – а вот это уже лингвистическое понятие (полиситуативность).  Не так важна длина предложения, как именно этот момент – **изображение двух  взглядов**,  которые можно сопоставить, сравнить, но  для этого надо выделить каждый из них  в отдельную тему.

**3. Практическое решение**

Если лингвисты уходят от этого вопроса, то он решается на практике **самим автором.** Как известно, практика письма обгоняет теорию письма. Именно это мы видим в приведенном примере. Делается **пауза**, которую нужно обозначить **запятой**.

По грамматическим показателям, названным выше, это сложное предложение, а ссылки на правило нет. Так давайте **честно скажем, что нет ссылки**, что этот вариант будет проходить как  **авторская пунктуация.**

Comment: Спасибо за интересный материал. Скажите, Shoron, по вашему мнению, отрывок из вопроса не соответствует хотя бы двумя признаками ситуации с однородными сказуемыми (Компактность расположения, одинаковая грамматическая форма)? Я так понимаю, что для того, чтобы признать их однозначно отдельными предикативными единицами, нужно, чтобы имелись все три полярных признака: некомпактность расположения, разная грамматическая форма, наличие собственных распространителей.

Comment: Вы знаете, немного я не успела, как раз хотела добавить в ответ  это пояснение. Всё-таки сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Теперь попробую ответить на ваш вопрос. Очевидный формальный признак однородности – это одна  грамматическая  форма,  даже один  и тот же глагол, но это ничего не решает здесь. Рассмотрим такое предложение: Я вижу Томаса  Беккета, и вижу смуглую женщину рядом с ним. Даже здесь надо поставить запятую, это тоже два взгляда, хотя два персонажа стоят рядом.  Если бы взгляд был один, то нужно было бы написать так: Я вижу Томаса  Беккета и смуглую женщину рядом с ним. Зачем повторять глагол? Повтор же глагола – это уже изображение двух ситуаций. Так я думаю. А формально решать этот вопрос нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

**Вместо вступления**

Как мне кажется, мы обычно воспринимаем  правила как  **инструкцию** (руководство) для правильного оформления текстов, но не более того. Писатель должен писать по правилам, потому что это требует редактор издательства,  а обычные люди соблюдают правила, чтобы считать себя грамотными и чтобы другие так же  считали. Если мы читаем книгу, то попутно интересуемся постановкой знаков  в целях своего развития: «Почему это писатель не поставил здесь запятую, а корректор пропустил.  Однородные члены, значит, запятая нужна». Но верна ли такая однозначная трактовка правил. Правила – это всё-таки не инструкция для грамотного письма.

Процитирую в очередной раз **Розенталя,** просто лучше об этом не скажешь: «Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает формальный подход к соблюдению правил».

Так давайте **следовать этому указанию**, когда решаем наши задачи и выбираем знаки препинания.

**Ответ на вопрос**

***Я вижу Томаса  Беккета, и (я) вижу смуглую женщину со шрамом, которая работает в корпусе Святого Петра в две тысячи двадцать пятом году.***

Примечание. **Томас Бекет** - канцлер короля Генриха II, глава английской Церкви, одна из ключевых фигур в истории XII века. Знаменит он тем, что настолько сумел насолить монарху, что был убит прямо у алтаря своей церкви.

**Из вузовской грамматики:** [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

ВОПРОС ОБ ОДНОРОДНЫХ СКАЗУЕМЫХ

В предложении может быть несколько сказуемых при одном и том же подлежащем. В связи с этим встает вопрос (не получивший в лингвистике однозначного решения), являются ли они простыми или сложными. Одни из них можно считать **простыми** предложениями с однородными сказуемыми, другие считаются промежуточными структурами между простым и **сложным** предложением.

Чем больше **степень спаянности** сказуемых, т. е. чем ближе они к однородному ряду, тем ближе предложение к простому. Наибольшая степень спаянности достигается, если сказуемые имеют одинаковое морфологическое выражение, **не распространены**, контактно расположены, связаны с общим второстепенным членом (дополнением или обстоятельством.  **При большей коммуникативной расчлененности** и самостоятельности частей, содержащих сказуемые, особенно при дифференцированных отношениях между сказуемыми, предложение приближается к сложному.

Итак,  с точки зрения грамматики, мы можем считать данную конструкцию  **сложным, а не простым предложением** с однородными членами. В этом случае мы имеем право поставить запятую в ССП.

Семантическая **расчлененность** явно чувствуется, а также  делается пауза чтении:  *я вижу, а также я вижу.* Ну и значительная **распространенность** второй части склоняет нас  к тому, чтобы считать предложение сложным.

**Комментарий**

1. Разбора подобных решений **нет у Розенталя**,  сослаться не на что, можно только рассмотреть  грамматику. Но это же не повод требовать от писателя отсутствия запятой,  даже если пауза явно слышится и требуется раздельное прочтение двух частей.
2. И вот уж не нужно искать **подходящее под запятую правило** где-то еще, чтобы сослаться хотя бы на что-то.  Потому что это не тема «Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания», нет здесь **значения добавочности.** Два взгляда автора на своих персонажей вполне **равноправны** и даны для сопоставления. Неверное толкование запятой приведет **к искажению смысла.**

Comment: Ни одного голоса, ни одного комментария  – дубль два другого ответа (нам толико столько, а больше не нужно)?   Но ведь это же форум лингвистов и любителей словесности, предложены два решения, а реакции никакой. Я не согласна с первым ответом, вы меня слышите, участники и автор вопроса?  Я стараюсь быть объективной, а вы нет? Можно было бы смягчить риторику, я обычно так и делаю по отношению к приятным мне людям (простите, Римма, за излишнюю резкость). Мне просто хотелось посмотреть, как сделают свой выбор добрые люди. Вдруг я все-таки тогда ошибалась…

Comment: Sharon, мне понятны Ваши эмоции. Не так давно я в вопросе о коте Баюне написал самый обстоятельный и, на мой взгляд, единственный верный ответ. И реакции тоже было ноль, хотя я поднял научные работы, углубился в вопрос. Однако это Интернет, никто не обязан круглосуточно мониторить темы и читать каждый ответ. Я вот, например, сегодня впервые зашёл со вчерашнего дня. Мог бы зайти и через неделю. Как это характеризует мою объективность? У всех своё свободное время. Не переживайте так.

Comment: Что касается Ваших рассуждений, то я считаю правильным тут ещё подискутировать. Вы говорите о том, что предложение может "приблизиться" к сложному, стать "промежуточным между сложным и простым". Вероятно, это пересказ какого-то источника. А вот Ваш вывод: "предложение мы можем считать сложным". Но ведь выше Вы нигде не сослались на то, что предложение с распространёнными сказуемыми можно считать сложным. Близким к сложному — да, но никак не сложным. Я считаю, что Вы в поисках объяснения гиперболизируете чьё-то мнение. Хотя не исключаю, что Вы на правильном пути.

Comment: В связи с этим у меня к Вам следующее предложение. Прочитав Ваш ответ, я поразмышлял над вопросом с новой точки зрения. У меня появилась своя версия. Я сейчас её сформулирую и опубликую в качестве ответа на свой вопрос. Там я буду приветствовать Ваше мнение, включая конструктивные возражения. Ну а здесь я Вам предлагаю продолжить обсуждать Вашу версию. В том, что это не случай присоединения, Вы меня убедили. А вот в том, что запятая нужна по приведённым Вами причинам, нет.

Comment: @Третий глаз  Спасибо за ваш комментарий, я вижу, что вы ответили мне, как только смогли это сделать. Возможно, чуть позже я дополню свой ответ. Но в любом случае я пересказывала вполне сложившееся мнение специалистов,  изложенное в учебной грамматике с 2004 года. В издании 2013 года оно повторяется еще раз. Попробую еще где-нибудь поискать, мне важно, чтобы вы с доверием отнеслись к моим словам.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, действительно стоило начать поиск решения с анализа оригинального текста.
В романе на английском языке ясно видно, что в предложении 2 грамматические основы: "я вижу"(1) и "я вижу" (2).

В переводе второе "я" опустили, создав иллюзию общего подлежащего, но синтаксис сохранили оригинальный, из-за чего рассуждения о причине постановки запятой увели не в ту степь.

Мнение, высказанное Sharon, я не могу назвать убедительным, так как мне не известны примеры, когда значительная распространённость сказуемого становилась основанием для постановки запятой при наличии союза "и". И это при том, что у многих авторов имеются весьма сложные грамматические конструкции и очень длинные предложения. Набоков, Пруст, Пинчон, Маркес, Уоллес (хотя последний и не заслуживает быть в этом списке) — авторы, очень любящие запятые и длинные сложные предложения. Но я не встречал в их переводах запятые между длинными сказуемыми. Потому не вижу причины для постановки запятой в отрывке из данного вопроса, даже если притвориться, будто подлежащее у нас общее. Бывали предложения и посложнее. Более того, отсутствие запятой как раз и способно нас сориентировать в длинном предложении — что и к чему относится, то есть какое существительное выполняет действие, обозначенное глаголом сказуемого. В крайнем случае для разграничения пауз справедливо использовать длинное тире, либо запятую с тире (такие примеры мне встречались в переводах Блаватской). Но в любом случае там не было бы союза "и".

Так можно ли в итоге поставить и запятую, и "и" в этом месте, если бы у нас в действительности имелось лишь одно, общее подлежащее на это предложение? Думаю, да. Такое решение есть.

Запятая бы ставилась по правилу разъединения однородных сказуемых. А "и" при этом не несло бы функцию сочинительного или присоединительного союза, а стало бы чисто поэтическим элементом, как во фразе "И грянул гром". Как и во многих других фразах, которые начинаются на "и", но это "и" никак не связано с предыдущим текстом. То есть фактически мы будем иметь предложение "я вижу это, вижу это", а "и" — не функциональный поэтический элемент фразы.