# Предложение сложное или с однородными членами?

Tags: синтаксис, однородные-члены, сложное-предложение

*Не было ни жилья, ни людей, не было ни рыбаков, ни сплавщиков, ни косарей, ни охотников.*

Это сложное предложение или "не было" – однородные сказуемые?

Answer (score 2):

1. **ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ**

Так, значит, мартышкин труд, возражений нет, так стоит ли браться? А если все-таки попробовать…

А что у нас там с мартышкой?

**МАРТЫШКИН ТРУД. БАСНЯ «ОБЕЗЬЯНА».** И.А. Крылов, 1811 год.

*От всех ему: спасибо, исполать!*

*Мартышку это в зависть вводит.*

*Хвалы приманчивы, — как их не пожелать!*

*Мартышка вздумала трудиться:*

*Нашла чурбан, и ну над ним возиться!*

*Рекой с бедняжки льется пот…*

*И наконец она, пыхтя, насилу дышит:*

*А всё ни от кого похвал себе не слышит.*

*И не диковинка, мой свет!*

*Трудишься много ты, да пользы в этом нет.*

Да уж, стоит задуматься, но все-таки с оценками спешить не стоит...

2. **ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

Семантика текста ясна, перед автором стояла  вполне определенная задача  –  раскрыть содержание собирательного  слова  ***люди***. По смыслу оно является **обобщающим словом** по отношению к однородному ряду – рыбаки, сплавщики, косари, охотники. Но вот  выбор **формы предложения** представляется оригинальным, художественным – автор  использует бессоюзную связь **с повтором глагола**.

Но бессоюзная связь  применяется как для  однородных членов, так и в сложном предложении. Можно ли здесь определить вид  синтаксической конструкции? Будет ли такое решение чисто **условным** (такое предположение уже высказано) или все-таки есть возможность поступить иначе?

Совсем недавно на форуме решался подобный вопрос с повтором глагола. Там (для меня) критерием стало явное наличие **паузы** между двумя частями. В этом случае мы видим **две ситуации**, то есть сложное предложение, а не однородные сказуемые. Повтор **однозначно** фиксирует эту сложность.
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464150/Запятая-между-одинаковыми-глаголами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464150/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

(Впрочем, ни один из данных ответов **не принят**, так что вопрос там остается **открытым**.)

Присмотримся **К ИНТОНАЦИИ** предложения – да, пауза присутствует,  после перечислительной интонации в первой части делается понижение голоса, а уже затем следует второе перечисление.

А если считать сказуемые **однородными**? О перечислительной интонации слышали все. Тогда попробуйте прочитать предложение, где фактически присутствуют три однородных ряда, требующих перечислительной интонации. **Разве это не надо учитывать? Разве это не говорит об однозначности решения?**

Итак, **я считаю**, что  **вывод вполне однозначный**: это бессоюзное сложное предложение, состоящее из двух простых безличных предложений – с двумя предикативными основами, а не с одной.

Было бы интересно **услышать мнение** других участников. Пожалуйста, **не самоустраняйтесь** по возможности. Я понимаю, что пунктуация не меняется, особой заитересованности в решении задачи нет. Но, может быть, лучше заранее определиться с решением всех подобных задач (с изменением знаков или без изменения знаков).

**3. ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Но все-таки для сравнения рассмотрим еще один пример.

***Не было ни жилья, ни денег, но было ощущение счастья***. Первая часть  (до союза НО)  – это  простое предложение.

Но даже его с помощью повтора глагола можно представить как сложное, обозначив две ситуации: ***Не было жилья, не было денег, но было ощущение счастья***.

Здесь первая  часть уже сложное предложение.  Автор изображает две ситуации, но делает это с определенной **художественной целью** – особенным образом подчеркнуть каждую из них.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку.

Answer (score 1):

Никто никогда не скажет вам этого. Такие вопросы в языкознании — это вопросы классификации. У нас есть какие-то общие характеристики обозначаемого термином, 60 процентов языковых ситуаций исходят из этих общих характеристик, еще 20 — следуют из каких-то более тонких соображений, остальные 20 не могут из чего-либо следовать, а могут являться только результатом договоренностей. Вот условимся, что эти безличные глаголы — однородные сказуемые, — будут однородными сказуемым, условимся иначе — будет иначе. Пунктуация в обоих случаях одинакова, так что, мое мнение, разбираться в этом — мартышкин труд.

Comment: Jim Korbett, не хотите ли вы защитить свой ответ? Например, в части интонации, да и вообще определиться с окончательным решением. Вы по-прежнему считате определение грамматики этого предложения мартышкиным трудом.  Я думаю, что у вас смелый и решительный характер и вы ответите мне.

Comment: Нет, не хочу. Я признаю вашу безоговорочную победу. Я даже поставлю вам плюсик, только не надо со мной спорить на эту тему.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, просто за то, что ответили. Я уже думала: отмолчитесь – не буду с вами дружить. Но вот не ошиблась в вас, что бесконечно приятно.

Comment: Я не могу на данный момент спорить на эту тему, так как не занимался детальной формализацией для себя всех этих случаев безличных сказуемых и подобного. Мне нужно день-два поразбираться в этом, но сейчас нет времени. Это не тоже самое, что дать короткий ответ по вопросу, которым я более менее занимался.